# Why is NavigationLink not pushing the next controller automatically even if the view is refreshed correctly?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have this view, that requests for photos permissions to the user and when those are granted I'd like to push the next controller. I'm trying like this, but it's not automatically pushing. 
Any help?

By the way, this is compiling correctly and it's working. Permissions are correctly requested to the user and the view is refreshed, but it doesn't push the next controller as I would expect.

This is the helper i use to request permissions:

```
class PhotosLibraryHelper : ObservableObject{
    static let shared = PhotosLibraryHelper()

    @Published var authorizationStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()

    @Published var requestingAuthorization = false

    @Published var authorized = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == .authorized

    func requestAuthorization(){
        self.requestingAuthorization = true
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (authorizationStatus) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.authorized = authorizationStatus == .authorized ? true : false
                self.authorizationStatus = authorizationStatus
                self.requestingAuthorization = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is part of the view i'm using:

```
struct PhotosPermissionView : View {

    @ObservedObject var photosLibraryHelper = PhotosLibraryHelper.shared

    @State var authorized = PhotosLibraryHelper.shared.authorized

    var body: some View {
....        
            ctaButton()

            NavigationLink(destination: ProductsView(), isActive: $authorized) {
                EmptyView()
            }
....
    }

    func ctaButton() -> AnyView {
        if (photosLibraryHelper.requestingAuthorization){
            return AnyView(CTAButton(loading:true))
        }else{
            switch photosLibraryHelper.authorizationStatus {
            case .authorized:
                return AnyView(NavigationLink(destination: ProductsView()){
                    CTAButton(title:"CONTINUE")
                })
            case .denied,
                 .restricted:
                return AnyView(NavigationLink(destination: PhotosPermissionView()){
                    CTAButton(title:"SETTINGS")
                })
            case .notDetermined:
                return AnyView(
                    Button(action: {
                        self.photosLibraryHelper.requestAuthorization()
                    }) {
                        CTAButton(title:"REQUEST")
                    }
                )
            @unknown default:
                return AnyView(NavigationLink(destination: PhotosPermissionView()){
                    CTAButton(title:"CONTINUE")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This one

```
@State var authorized = PhotosLibraryHelper.shared.authorized
```

is only initial value settings, it is not changed anywhere afterwards.

Actually you don't need local state. Navigation link can be bound directly to published property of helper

```
NavigationLink(destination: ProductsView(), isActive: $photosLibraryHelper.authorized) {
    EmptyView()
}
```

Comment: This works but just as a clarification I was changing the value of the published property in the photoslibraryhelper class. Why was not affecting the state property of the view?

Comment: Because initial assignment is not binding, it is just set initial value, state should be changed somewhere later in view to have effect.